# Redis stored procedures like functionality

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm trying to implement a basic service that receives a msg and time in the future and once the time arrives, it prints the msg.

I want to implement it with Redis.

While investigating the capabilities of Redis I've found that I can use https://redis.io/topics/notifications on expired keys together with subscribing I get what I want.

But I am facing a problem, if the service is down for any reason, I might lose those expiry triggers.

To resolve that issue, I thought of having a queue (in Redis as well) which will store expired keys and once the service is up, it will pull them all the expired values, but for that, I need some kind of "stored procedure" that will handle the expiry routing.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to do that.
So the question is: is it possible to implement with the current capabilities of Redis, and also, do I have alternatives?

Comment: This is a pointer: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/5766#issuecomment-620623878